# No manual entries for recvfrom, sendto, and bind commands in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: manpage, bind

I run Ubuntu 18.04 through Oracle VirtualBox. In the terminal man commands for recvfrom, sendto, bind do not show any manual entries as shown below.

```
rishi@rishi-VirtualBox:~$ man recvfrom  
No manual entry for recvfrom
rishi@rishi-VirtualBox:~$ man sendto
No manual entry for sendto
rishi@rishi-VirtualBox:~$ man bind  
No manual entry for bind
```

Comment: The files are `/usr/share/man/man2/recv.2.gz`, `/usr/share/man/man2/send.2.gz` and `/usr/share/man/man2/bind.2.gz`. What's the value of your `$MANPATH`?

Comment: Btw MANPATH is probably unset and generally should be. If it is set, that could be a cause for concern

Answer (score 3):

If you want to read the manual pages of the *system calls* by these names (as opposed to the *command-line applications* outlined in [karel’s answer](/a/1064034/175814)) please make sure that the `manpages-dev` package is installed:

```
sudo apt install manpages-dev
```

If you prefer the manual pages to be translated to your language you can list available translation packages with:

```
apt-cache search 'manpages-.*-dev'
```